# How to find and replace from a List in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not using VBA but just simple excel, can anyone help me find a solution to this problem? Would greatly appreciate it!

I have a list of Names in **Sheet 1** like below

| - | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sp_abc_**Rick** |
| 2 | sp_abc_**Jabba_the** |
| 3 | sp_abc_**Dany** |
| 4 | sp_random_**Rick** |
| 5 | sp_random_**Jabba_the** |
| 6 | sp_random_**Dany** |
| 7 | sp_constant |
| 8 | sp_ripley_art_**Dany** |
| 9 | sp_ripley_art_**Jabba_the** |
| 10 | sp_wakeup |

I have a list of Mapping Table in **Sheet 2** like below

| - | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Rick** | **Morty** |
| 2 | **Jabba_the** | **Hutt** |
| 3 | **Dany** | **Dragon** |

I wish to have a result in **Sheet 1**, in **column B**, like below

| - | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sp_abc_**Rick** | sp_abc_**Morty** |
| 2 | sp_abc_**Jabba_the** | sp_abc_**Hutt** |
| 3 | sp_abc_**Dany** | sp_abc_**Dragon** |
| 4 | sp_random_**Rick** | sp_random_**Morty** |
| 5 | sp_random_**Jabba_the** | sp_random_**Hutt** |
| 6 | sp_random_**Dany** | sp_random_**Dragon** |
| 7 | sp_constant | sp_constant |
| 8 | sp_ripley_art_**Dany** | sp_ripley_art_**Dragon** |
| 9 | sp_ripley_art_**Jabba_the** | sp_ripley_art_**Hutt** |
| 10 | sp_wakeup | sp_wakeup |

To give you a context of the number of rows. Sheet 1 will be bigger with more than 1000 rows. Sheet 2 (Mapping Table) is constant set of rows. Currently it is about 100 rows.

Comment: you can use =FIND to find the position of the last underscore, return the String right of its position and VLOOPKUP the Match from the mapping table. Then do the same to concatenate the first part of the original string with your Lookup result.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are underscores in the Find Text. I just re-edited my problem statement to reflect that.

Comment: @GaryTheBrave try the one I have shown below. It worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a formula like shown below using `LOOKUP()`, `SEARCH()` with `SUBSTITUTE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH($D$1:$D$3,A1),$D$1:$D$3),
LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH($D$1:$D$3,A1),$E$1:$E$3)),A1)
```

---

Comment: ... `Lookup(far_too_big_number, range)` is the same as "find the last cell in `range`, containing a value". Never heard of that neat trick :-)

Comment: @Dominique `Old School` approach.

Comment: @GaryTheBrave glad to know it worked for you =)

Answer (score 1):

There you go. There may have other better solution. This is what I got.

All in column B.

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT(MID(A1,1,MATCH(1,(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:$Z$255),1))<90)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:$Z$255),1))>=65),FALSE)-1),INDIRECT(CONCAT("sheet2!b", MATCH(MID(A1, MATCH(1,(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:$Z$255),1))<90)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:$Z$255),1))>=65),FALSE), LEN(A1)), Sheet2!$A$1:Sheet2!$A$300, 0)))),A1)
```

Break down is as follow;

Let's start put things from Column C onward.

Column C, to find the index of the first capital letter from the text.
ref: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/02/21/find-position-of-first-capital-letter-in-a-string/

```
=MATCH(1,(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:$Z$255),1))<90)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($Z$1:$Z$255),1))>=65),FALSE)
```

Column D, cut the name part by using upper case letter index from column C, sp_abc_Jabba_the -> Jabba_the

```
=MID(A1, C1, LEN(A1))
```

Column E, search row number from Sheet2 by matching Column D's name with Sheet 2's Column A, this will get matching row number from Sheet2.

```
=MATCH(D1, Sheet2!$A$1:Sheet2!$A$300, 0)
```

Column F, get Sheet2's Column B value by the row number from Column E.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCAT("sheet2!b", E1))
```

Column G,

1. Cut "sp_abc_" from "sp_abc_Rick"
2. Concat "sp_abc_" with Column F's "Morty".
3. If there is any error, use Column A value as default.

. <- this dot is intentional. please ignore.

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT(MID(A1,1,C1-1),F1),A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=BYROW(A1:A10,LAMBDA(a,LET(b,TEXTBEFORE(a&"|","_"&A12:A14&"|",-1),IFERROR(CONCAT(IF(b&"_"&A12:A14=a,b&"_"&B12:B14,"")),a))))
```

The concatenation with a "|" would assert we only replace values when at the exact end of the input. Just in case there would be a stray (for example) '*Rick*' somewhere before the end.